# Communicate between my menucontroller and my formcontroller (or another way to show a navigate away message)

Tags: angularjs

I have a navigationbar in the menu at the top of my site with it's own `controller`.
The main part of the site is a form with it own `controller` (call it the formcontroller).

Now when the user clicks a link on the menu to navigate to a different page, I want to show a message 'are you sure?' when the form is not `Pristine`.

So what I thought of is that the `menucontroller` has to somehow ask the `formcontroller` 'is the form pristine?'

Now my first question is if this is the right way to implement this behaviour, to let the `menucontroller` have knowledge of the `formcontroller`.
And if so, how can I make them communicate?

Then if this not the way to implement this, what is the right way of doing this?

EDIT, some background:

It's as single page app, the page is devided in two parts; the menu is in it's own 'ui-view' and the form is loaded via the ui-router in it's own 'ui-view'.

Comment: obviously, you can use this method!! use a service to communicate between a controller.

Comment: let me know if you need code sample

Comment: Instead of the menu controller asking if the form controller is pristine, that would involve the menu controller knowing of the form controller. How about the form controller tells the menu to prompt for navigation. Either through events or a service. Then the blocking logic is in the menu where it should be and its generic so any page can request to block navigation and that logic for choosing to block is where is should be, in the form. Also is it a single page app? Is the menu controller always present, and the form controller loaded in a partial?

Comment: @ste2425 I've edited the question. When you say though a service, is that a angular service which I inject in every controller, and then I update it in the formcontroller and the menucontroller reads from it?

Comment: @Michel ill write it up in answer, its quite large for a comment, then i can give some code examples too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to refer to your form controller as content controller because this implementation doesn't limit it to just a form, it could be any controller doing anything in your app.

As said in my comment I would spin it round, have the menu controller be told if it should block navigation. Then your content controller can tell the menu if it should prompt. That way its generic and expandable to different content controllers. (What if you want the same on something that isn't a form for example). you menu isn't having to worry about specific implementations of your content controllers.

---

One option would be using events. This would involve your menu controller having a flag to store if the navigation should be blocked. It would listen to an event and set the flag accordingly.

```
//In your menu controller
var prompt = false;

$scope.navigate = function (path) {
    if (prompt) {
        //prompt
    } else {
        //navigate
    }
}

$scope.$on('navigation.prompt', function (e, p) {
    prompt = p;
});
```

To use it elsewhere:

```
$scope.$emit('navigation.prompt', true);
```

There is one thing to bear in mind. Ive not used `ui-view` so I'm not too sure its hierarchy of scopes for each 'view' so you may have to use `$emit` or `$broadcast` to send the event out (one goes up the scope tree, the other down).

---

The other option would be a service. This means you wouldn't need to worry about scope hierarchy (if it even would be an issue) but it does mean you have to inject it in any content controller that you want to block navigation in.

Exactly the same concept except the service has the flag, then you set and read it.

This could either be with getter/setter method or just expose a property directly.

```
app.service('navigationPrompt', function () {
    this.prompt = false; //Access directly

    //or with getters/setters
    this.get = function () {
        return this.prompt;
    }

    this.set = function (v) {
        this.prompt = v;
    }
});
```

---

I've not used `ui-view` before but i have done similar using angulars native partials and the way that works is your menu controller persists its state across the life time of the application whilst the content controller is lost when you navigate. So if your implementation is the same you would have to reset the flag in either approach when you navigate in case your new content controller doesn't set it.

The cool thing about have your content communicate with your menu in this way is your service or events could be expanded to allow your content to disable navigation routes, hide them or manipulate them in other ways.

Comment: Thanks very much for this great answer! One thing I wonder: when two controllers get injected a service, do they get the same reference? Is it a sort of singleton? Otherwise wouldn't the one controller set properties on service instance A and would the menucontroller read from instance B?

Comment: No problem, `services` are singletons, angular 'instantiates' it on the first request and shares that to all others, `factories` on the other hand are not. They deal with creating new things.

Comment: Related question: How can I 'listen' for Form.$pristine changes? I guess I have to let the form inform the controller that the pristine state changes so that the controller can set the property on the service. I can't find a way to hook into the Form.$pristine event. Or is there a general way to listen to changes in Angular objects?